# How to create health check in Grafana?

Tags: java, devops, grafana, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I have a running Docker container Spring Boot + Spring Boot Actuator + Prometheus.

Grafana is also running as a Docker image and JVM (Micrometer) dashboard is displayed correctly.

My task is to create an alert that invokes in case `/api/actuator/health` doesn't return `200 {"status":"UP"}`.

Could you tell me how can I create such alert?

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/alerting/rules/ Take a look here

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that :

[image]

[image]

For the notification , you have to set up the notification channel in the alerting panel, to the left.

Comment: Could I ask you, does Grafana poll Prometheus in your case? What should I put instead of "localhost:9117"?

Comment: Yes, it is. For your metrics, you can copy it from prometheus : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cOLl.png

Comment: @Pasha or anyone who may advise here, what is the best way to check the health of your web service/application in this case, not necessarily /actuator/health but any other /health endpoint and to return either 200 or other relevant status code?

Answer (score 2):

I just created a new dashboard with "up" query and it works. Only "up" in query and that's it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[blackbox-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) can help you in this case. You can use blackbox exporter to monitor the application's status. You just need to specify the target URL to query an endpoint. Look at an [example](https://geekflare.com/monitor-website-with-blackbox-prometheus-grafana) here.